# How to create independent Monaco editor instances?

Tags: monaco-editor

If I create 2 Monaco Instances on the same website using typescript, then they interfere.

For example, I define in both a function foo, then I get an error that the method does already exists.

I assume that behind the scenes they share “state”.

Is there an easy way to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance!